# how to add an extra character after exactly two character on each line in vim

Tags: text, edit, vim, textedit

I have the text in the file like this:

```
in IDMAN
ip frghj
```

I want the text to be like this:

```
in *IDMAN
ip *frghj
```

Comment: The title of your question says "each line" but in your example the extra character is only on the first line.

Comment: and also after 3rd character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example file:

```
in IDMAN
ip frghj
```

and the following output (a star on each line):

```
in *IDMAN
ip *frghj
```

The sequence of commands is the following (cursor has to be on the character where the addition should happen):

```
CTRL-vjI*ESC
```

That means:

- CTRL-v: Start visual block mode
- j: Mark the second line too
- I: Go into input mode for the block
- *: Insert the character(s)
- ESC: Close the visual input mode, so to all marked lines, the characters will be added.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
:%s/\%3c/*
```

Explanation:

- `:s` is the substitute command, `%` is the range for all lines in the file
- `/` is the pattern delimiter
- `\%3c` is a pattern that matches nothing at third character in the line
- `*` is the substitution expression

Comment: One can use just `:%s/\%3c/*`, the `&` sign is completely unnecessary here.  The `\%c` atom is a zero-width match, therefore matched string is always empty in this case.

Comment: Also, your alternative command is incorrect, it does not have the same effect as the first one.  The latter inserts a star after the first *two* characters of a line, while the former do that after the first *three* characters.  Please, check commands before posting.

Answer (score 4):

Hover your cursor over the capital `I` in `IDMAN` in normal mode.

[image]

Enter visual block selection with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and go down a line with `j`.

[image]

Enter insert mode with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> and then enter your desired character.

[image]

Go back to normal mode with <kbd>ESC</kbd> and the character will appear in the same column for the rest of the lines.

[image]

Comment: +1 for illustrated guide and accuracy. Also note that it is possible to select previous column in blockwise mode and hit A instead of I. Also if the `startofline` option is not set, hitting `G` will go to the last line, keeping the current column.

Answer (score 0):

How to add an `*` character after exactly *three* character on *each* line in vim:

```
:%s/\(...\)/\1*/
```

see `:help :s`, `:help range`, `:help s/\\1`

or, more shortly (great thanks to @Benoit for  :-) )

```
:%s/.../&*/
```

see `help s/\&` (thank @Benoit for being pointed to this)